# Inaccurate output when using importrange vs manual input

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, importrange, regexextract

I have a little problem using Google Sheets. I'm using `importrange` to get raw data from another sheet that I don't own. [This is the sample raw data](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1kXMXIfMIJfeedjUYluvGf1NaAPznWycfmq5nM3klbZo/edit#gid=0), then import it my own sheet [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1TyFQ793xz7_AgdfugC_W0Y3kKKJsDGTIAqd4lPvbsug/edit#gid=1924729276).

Importing data doesn't cause problems. However, whenever I am computing the score (using the MIN function) the output is not accurate with the imported data and when manually inputted the score, the output is correct. Please see the arrows with the examples.

Your feedback on this will be appreciated.

Comment: Please add the formulas and sample data to the question it's self as well the address to the cells having the formulas that you want that we look to. Also explain whit is regexextract tag included on this question.

Answer (score 0):

You can either convert percentual output from a query to the number or add **`*100`** as a correction:

```
=MIN(120%,(REGEXEXTRACT(TO_TEXT(C6),"\d+.\d+")/0.9))*10%
```




```
=MIN(120%,((C6*100)/0.9))*10%
```

Comment: Hi guys, this is a follow-up. I'm just wondering. I tried to enter manual score below 100.00%, however, it still gave the maximum score of 12%. Also, aside from that, I tried to lower score but still get the 12%. Please help me! :(

Comment: @Ben edit your question and include exactly what you want to accomplish by explaining how you want to calculate what and where and add some examples of desired output.

Comment: If you notice on the cell C5 was entered manually and the result was right it should be the maximum of 12% however, when I manually enter a score that is less than by 100% (with REGEXEXTRACT(TO_TEXT() formula) it still gives the same result of 12%. Please see comparison result between C8 and C9 to their converted score.  
  
In addition, this is the thing that I want to accomplished.

Comment: --The sheet will automatically compute the scores using the _query_ function as the basis of their scores.